# Smoothing polygons in contour map?

Tags: python, open-source-gis, contour, smoothing, spline

Here is a contour map for which all the polygons of levels are available.

Let ask **how to smooth the polygons keeping all vertices preserved in their exact locations?**

Indeed the contour is made on top of a grid data, you may suggest then to smooth the grid data and hence the resulting contour will be smoother. Note that this is not working as my desire since the smoothing function such as Gaussian filter will remove small packs of data and will change the range of the third variable e.g., the height which are not allowed in my application.

Actually I'm looking for a piece of code (preferably in **Python**) which can do the smoothing of 2D polygons (any type: convex, concave, self-intersecting etc) reasonably painless (forget pages of codes) and accurate.

FYI, there is [a function in ArcGIS](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Smooth_Polygon_%28Data_Management%29) that does this perfectly, but using third party commercial applications is not my choice for this question.

[image]

---

**1)**

Scipy.interpolate:

[image]

As you see the resulting splines (red) are not satisfactory!

**2)**

Here is the result using the code given in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246525/how-can-i-draw-a-bezier-curve-using-pythons-pil). It is not working well!

[image]

**3)**

To me the best solution should be something like the following figure in which a square is being smoothed gradually by changing only one value. I hope for similar concept for smoothing any form of polygons.

[image]

Satisfying the condition that spline passes the points:

[image]

**4)**

Here is my implementation of "whuber's idea" line by line in **Python** on his data. There are possibly some bugs since the results are not good.

[image]

K=2 is a disaster and so for k>=4.

**5)**

I removed one point in the problematic location and the resulting spline is now identical to whuber's. But it is still a question that why the method does not work for all cases?

[image]

**6)**

A good smoothing for whuber's data can be as follows (drawn by vector graphics software) in which an extra point has been smoothly added (compare with update

4):

[image]

**7)**

See the result from Python version of whuber's code for some iconic shapes:

[image]
**Note** that the method seems doesn't work for polylines. For the corner polyline (contour) green is what I want but got red. This needs to be addressed since contour maps are always polylines although closed polylines can be treated as polygons as in my examples. Also not that the problem emerged in update 4 has not been addressed yet.

**8) [my last]**

Here is the final solution (not perfect!):

[image]

Remember that you will have to do something about the area pointed by stars.  There is perhaps a bug in my code or the proposed method needs further development to consider all situations and to provide desired outputs.

Comment: how are you generating 'polygon' contours? wouldn't they always be lines, since a contour intersecting the edge of a DEM would never close upon itself?

Comment: i've used the v.generalize function in GRASS to do smoothing of contour lines with decent results, although it can take awhile for maps with very dense contours.

Comment: @pistachionut You may consider the contour levels are poly-lines. I'm looking for **pure code** at the first stage. If not available then light package for Python.

Comment: Perhaps look at http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Interpolation because it sounds like you want to spline

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for the link. I put some results in the question, update 1. They are not satisfactory at all!

Comment: This answer can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246525/how-can-i-draw-a-bezier-curve-using-pythons-pil

Comment: It seems to me that some of the artefacts are caused by repeating points, causing a corner in the curve. Do you maybe feed the function with the polygon definition without removing the duplicated start/end point? (Or actually, it might be the opposite, that Scipy.interpolate does not consider the curve a loop)

Comment: @relet I think your second guess is correct. There is always a corner. Furthermore, the drawn splines are not close enough to the polygons!

Comment: @Pablo I already tested your given link with many improvements. However there is always a bothering corner in the resulting spline. Indeed the spline starts from a point and finishes to it! I added my results in Update 2.

Comment: Re update 1: why are the results "unsatisfactory"?  Is it perhaps because you are not using a circular (periodic) spline?  A simple trick will help: cyclically extend the list of vertices at both ends.  Add as many vertices as the order of the spline (e.g., for a cubic spline add three vertices at each end).  Compute the spline and restrict it to the original list of vertices.  There will be no endpoint effects now.

Comment: @whuber To me there are not satisfactory 1) there is always a corner effect 2) there are large distances between curve and segments 3) they don't keep the overall shape preserved.

Comment: (1) Any "corner effect" is because you are doubling one vertex (to serve as start and end of the polygon boundary).  Remove the doubled vertex.  (2) Control the distances by using different kinds of splines.  For example, take a linear combination of a spline and the original polygon.  (3) By definition, smoothing a polygon will change its shape.  You can't hope to preserve that!

Comment: @whuber For the case shown in update 4 there is no duplicated point, still there is self-intersecting problem!

Comment: That's almost surely a bug in your code.  Such a cusp is not possible using a cubic spline.

Comment: @whuber Add `xy = rbind(xy,c(1.8,-0.8))` you'll see what I meant. The same cusp in R result.

Comment: @Pablo Bezier curve in your link works well for polylines. whuber's works almost well for polygons. So they together could address the question. Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge for free.

Comment: Well, yes: if you force a cusp by densely sampling near a vertex, you will get a cusp!  One would think that is a desirable feature of the smoothing method.  For smoothers to work well, you either need to leave sufficiently large gaps between vertices or you need to relax the requirement that the smoother pass through the vertices.

Comment: re Edit 7: To spline polylines, simply omit the preliminary wrapping-around of vertices (set `k=0` in my solution: I have edited it to make that case work correctly).  Re Bezier curves: they do not accomplish what you want, because they do not pass through the vertices.

Comment: @whuber Yes, you're right. Bezier curves do not pass through the given points. I updated my code as your recommendation and got the results shown in update 8.

Comment: Interpolation with Bezier Curves. A very simple method of smoothing polygons: http://www.antigrain.com/research/bezier_interpolation/

Comment: Similar question and good solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31466013/2829863

Comment: TopoJSON may be an option. It is a topological data model as its name implies and simplification methods are available through the API. Check out this blog post for more info. - https://www.perrygeo.com/tag/topojson.html.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Most methods to spline sequences of numbers will spline polygons.  The trick is to make the splines "close up" smoothly at the endpoints.  To do this, "wrap" the vertices around the ends.  Then spline the x- and y-coordinates separately.

Here is a working example in `R`.  It uses the default cubic `spline` procedure available in the basic statistics package.  For more control, substitute almost any procedure you prefer: just make sure it splines *through* the numbers (that is, interpolates them) rather than merely using them as "control points."

```
#
# Splining a polygon.
#
#   The rows of 'xy' give coordinates of the boundary vertices, in order.
#   'vertices' is the number of spline vertices to create.
#              (Not all are used: some are clipped from the ends.)
#   'k' is the number of points to wrap around the ends to obtain
#       a smooth periodic spline.
#
#   Returns an array of points. 
# 
spline.poly <- function(xy, vertices, k=3, ...) {
    # Assert: xy is an n by 2 matrix with n >= k.

    # Wrap k vertices around each end.
    n <- dim(xy)[1]
    if (k >= 1) {
        data <- rbind(xy[(n-k+1):n,], xy, xy[1:k, ])
    } else {
        data <- xy
    }

    # Spline the x and y coordinates.
    data.spline <- spline(1:(n+2*k), data[,1], n=vertices, ...)
    x <- data.spline$x
    x1 <- data.spline$y
    x2 <- spline(1:(n+2*k), data[,2], n=vertices, ...)$y

    # Retain only the middle part.
    cbind(x1, x2)[k < x & x <= n+k, ]
}
```

To illustrate its use, let's create a small (but complicated) polygon.

```
#
# Example polygon, randomly generated.
#
set.seed(17)
n.vertices <- 10
theta <- (runif(n.vertices) + 1:n.vertices - 1) * 2 * pi / n.vertices
r <- rgamma(n.vertices, shape=3)
xy <- cbind(cos(theta) * r, sin(theta) * r)
```

Spline it using the preceding code.  To make the spline smoother, increase the number of vertices from 100; to make it less smooth, decrease the number of vertices.

```
s <- spline.poly(xy, 100, k=3)
```

To see the results, we plot (a) the original polygon in dashed red, *showing* the gap between the first and last vertices (i.e., not closing its boundary polyline); and (b) the spline in gray, once more showing its gap.  (Because the gap is so small, its endpoints are highlighted with blue dots.)

```
plot(s, type="l", lwd=2, col="Gray")
lines(xy, col="Red", lty=2, lwd=2)
points(xy, col="Red", pch=19)
points(s, cex=0.8)
points(s[c(1,dim(s)[1]),], col="Blue", pch=19)
```

[image: Splined polygon]

Comment: Nice answer.  Is there any way to guarantee contours don't end up crossing as a result of smoothing?

Comment: That's a good question, @Kirk.  I am not aware of any method to guarantee non-crossing from this form of smoothing. (In fact, I don't even see how to guarantee that the smoothed polyline is non-self-intersecting.  This is not a big issue for most contours though.) In order to do that, you would need to return to the original DEM and instead use a better method to compute the contours in the first place.  (There *are* better methods--they have been known for a long time--but AFAIK some of the most popular GISes do not use them.)

Comment: First, I am still working to implement your answer in Python, yet not successful. Second, what will be the resulting if you apply your method on a square? You may refer to those I've drawn in the question.

Comment: My Python implementation of your method generates not enough good results, see update 4. BTW, I used `Scipy.interpolate.interp1d` and followed all your steps one by one.

Comment: I solved that problem. I had one more point there. However it brought to my attention how sensitive the method is to even one additional point very close to the original points.

Comment: The problem appeared for the algorithm indeed looks like self-intersecting problem demonstrated in update 4. Do you have any solution?

Comment: I accepted this as answer since it gives a good solution. Even though it is not a perfect one but it gave me some ideas working around, hope I'll find a solution that satisfies the points I mentioned above in my question and comments. You also may consider whuber's comments for the question [QC], there are good tricks there. Lastly I should say the translation to python is almost straightforward having lovely Scipy package installed. Also consider Pablo's comment in QC as possible solution for polylines, i.e., Bezier curves. Good luck everyone.

Comment: seeing your answers, I regret not taking care of my maths well!!!

Comment: This solution works well if you first take the convex hull of a set of points and then spline it. But, of course, that may not be ideal in all situations.

Comment: @rmf Could you explain why convexity plays, or should play, any role in this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but it showed up on Google for something I was looking for, so I thought I'd post my solution.

I don't see this as a 2D curve fitting exercise, but rather a 3D one. By considering the data as 3D we can ensure that the curves never cross one another, and can use information from other contours to improve our estimate for the current one.

The following iPython extract uses cubic interpolation provided by SciPy. Note that the z values I've plotted aren't important, as long as all the contours are equidistant in height.

```
In [1]: %pylab inline
        pylab.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 10)
        Populating the interactive namespace from numpy and matplotlib

In [2]: import scipy.interpolate as si

        xs = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 4.5, 4.5,
                       0.3, 1.5, 2.3, 3.8, 3.7, 2.3,
                       1.5, 2.2, 2.8, 2.2,
                       2.1, 2.2, 2.3])
        ys = np.array([0.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0,
                       1.1, 2.3, 2.5, 2.3, 1.1, 0.5,
                       1.1, 2.1, 1.1, 0.8,
                       1.1, 1.3, 1.1])
        zs = np.array([0,   0,   0,   0,
                       1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,
                       2,   2,   2,   2,
                       3,   3,   3])
        pts = np.array([xs, ys]).transpose()

        # set up a grid for us to resample onto
        nx, ny = (100, 100)
        xrange = np.linspace(np.min(xs[zs!=0])-0.1, np.max(xs[zs!=0])+0.1, nx)
        yrange = np.linspace(np.min(ys[zs!=0])-0.1, np.max(ys[zs!=0])+0.1, ny)
        xv, yv = np.meshgrid(xrange, yrange)
        ptv = np.array([xv, yv]).transpose()

        # interpolate over the grid
        out = si.griddata(pts, zs, ptv, method='cubic').transpose()

        def close(vals):
            return np.concatenate((vals, [vals[0]]))

        # plot the results
        levels = [1, 2, 3]
        plt.plot(close(xs[zs==1]), close(ys[zs==1]))
        plt.plot(close(xs[zs==2]), close(ys[zs==2]))
        plt.plot(close(xs[zs==3]), close(ys[zs==3]))
        plt.contour(xrange, yrange, out, levels)
        plt.show()
```

[image: Cubic Interpolated Result]

The results here don't look the best, but with so few control points they are still perfectly valid. Note how the green fitted line is pulled out to follow the wider blue contour.

Comment: The fitted smooth curves should stay close as possible to the original polygon / polyline.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote almost exactly the package you are looking for... but it was in Perl, and was over a decade ago: [GD::Polyline](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LDS/GD-2.18/GD/Polyline.pm).  It used 2D cubic Bezier curves, and would "smooth" an arbitrary Polygon or "Polyline" (my name then for what is now commonly called a "LineString").

The algorithm was two steps: given the points in the Polygon, add two Bezier control points between every point; then call a simple algorithm to make a piecewise approximation of the spline.

The second part is easy; the first part was a bit of art.  Here was the insight: consider a "control segment" a Vertex N: `vN`.  The control segment was three co-linear points: `[cNa, vN, cNb]`.  The center point was the vertex.  The slope of this control seg was equal to the slope from Vertex N-1 to Vertex N+1.  The length of the left portion of this segment was 1/3 the length from Vertex N-1 to Vertex N, and the length of the right portion of this segment was 1/3 the length from Vertex N to Vertex N+1.

If the original curve was four vertices:  `[v1, v2, v3, v4]` then the each vertex now get a control segment of the form: `[c2a, v2, c2b]`.  String these together like this: `[v1, c1b, c2a, v2, c2b, c3a, v3, c3b, c4a, v4]` and munch them four at a time as the four Bezier points: `[v1, c1b, c2a, v2]`, then `[v2, c2b, c3a, v3]`, and so on.  Because `[c2a, v2, c2b]` were co-linear, the resulting curve will be smooth at each vertex.

So this also meets your requirement to parameterize the "tightness" of the curve: use a smaller value than 1/3 for a "tighter" curve, a larger one for a "loopier" fit.  In either case, the resulting curve always passes through the original given points.

This resulted in a smooth curve that "circumscribed" the original Polygon.  I also had some way to "inscribe" a smooth curve... but I don't see that in the CPAN code.

Anyway, I don't at this time have a version available in Python, nor do I have any figures.  BUT... if/when I do port this to Python, I'll be sure to post here.

Comment: Cannot evaluate the Perl code, add graphics to demonstrate how it was working if possible.