# How do I smooth edges of polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, polygon, simplify, smoothing

Is there a built in function or plugin I can use to achieve smooth lines for my polygons instead of the blocky ones I have now?

[image]

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24827 is related but does not address exactly this question. Note, too, that these polygon clearly were derived from raster data, opening the question up to answers that show how to smooth categorical rasters.

Comment: I belive that this post will help you as well: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185096/why-are-the-holes-in-my-polygons-not-generalized

Answer (score 4):

You have to choose GRASS commands -> v.generalize. In parameters you need to choose Input polygon and one of the simplifications methods. Personaly I prefer snakes because it creates very nice smoothed border.