# Why are the holes in my polygons not generalized?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, generalization

I have one polygon layer with many holes. I would like to generalize it. I used v.generalize of grass. With it, I used chaiken algorithm. But, only the borders of polygons were generalized, the holes in them haven't smoothed their edges.

What can I do to smooth all edges (adding hole edges) of polygon?

[image: Holes with serrated edges]

Comment: I would explode polygons in outer shell and holes, generalize them, and again build donut polygons. Cannot check which commands to use for this at the moment.

Comment: Does this problem also happen in GRASS GIS 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use the brand new geoalgorithm from QGIS 2.14.1, named Smooth.py

With **Smooth Geometry** it's possible to smooth the entire polygon, not only the boundaries, as in Chaiken method from v.generalize

Comment: Interesting, will have to try out QGIS 2.14 sometime soon!

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing you are using GRASS `6.4.x` as there were issues regarding [generalizing polygons with holes](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/generalize-polygons-including-holes-td5185436.html). This has been fixed in GRASS 7, although I do not have this version so cannot confirm it.

A workaround would be to use the **Fill holes** tool from the *Processing Toolbox* on your original layer:

[image: Example polygon]

[image: Filled holes]

Use the **Difference** tool on both the *original* and *filled* layers:

[image: Difference]

Use the **v.generalize** tool on both the *filled* and the *difference* layers:

[image: Filled generalized]

[image: Difference generalized]

Finally, run the **Difference** tool again on both the *generalized* layers:

[image: Final result]

Comment: I think to do as you advice me. Even solve the problem of my question, your solution seem a little hard. I will check what the version which I do my work. You are rigth, the grass version is 6.4.x. I will do in 7.0 version and tell you what happen. Thanks

Comment: @DiogoCaribé - Perhaps you could share your shapefile so that others could test it using other methods?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best generalization tool out there is http://www.mapshaper.org/ and it seems to handle holes just fine. Super easy to use/much shorter workaround. I usually use the visvalingam algorithm.

[image]

Comment: I don't like this tool. Better, I dislike the its algorithm. The result is so rude. There are others algorithm that smooth polygons continuous.