# Using Chaiken Method parameters for smoothing polygon vectors in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, simplify, smoothing

I've been trying to smooth a huge polygon, that is result of a segmentation export. I'd like to know what's the best parameters to use Chaiken Method to get smooth curved boundaries on QGIS 2.14.

I already tried v.generalize
[image]

The best result I got so far is this:
[image]

And what I really need is something like this:
[image]

I made this red line on adobe illustrator as example.
So, how can I get this result on QGIS 2.14?

Comment: This question has already been answered. See here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185096/why-are-the-holes-in-my-polygons-not-generalized

Comment: Actually, it hasn't. They are two different questions, about the same subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try simplifying your polygon before running the smooth operation. Polygons with many nodes don't respond well to the Chaiken algorithm.

Comment: It worked, ndawson! Nice tip.

Comment: @Edu - Don't forget to accept ndawson's answer if it worked for you by clicking the green-faded tick on the left hand side =)

Comment: Okay, @Joseph - I'll do that right now.