# problem with polygon smoothing in R

Tags: polygon, r, smoothing

With R I am looking to smooth my Polygon:
[inter2.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1fwv3e5pthm2uw/inter2.csv?dl=0)

code:

```
inter1 <- read.table("c:/inter2.csv", header=TRUE)

# add a category (required for later rasterizing/polygonizing)
inter1 <- cbind(inter1, cat = rep(1L, nrow(inter1)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# convert to spatial points
coordinates(inter1) <- ~long + lat

# gridify your set of points
gridded(inter1) <- TRUE

# convert to raster
r <- raster(inter1)

# convert raster to polygons
sp <- rasterToPolygons(r, dissolve = T)
plot(sp)
# addition transformation to distinguish well the set of polygons
polys <- slot(sp@polygons[[1]], "Polygons")

require(Hmisc) # for Bezier curve
output <- SpatialPolygons(
  Srl = lapply(1:length(polys),
               function(x){
                 p <- polys[[x]]

                 #applying bezier curve for smoothing polygon edges
                 px <- slot(polys[[x]], "coords")[,1]
                 py <- slot(polys[[x]], "coords")[,2]
                 bz <- bezier(px, py)
                 slot(p, "coords") <- as.matrix(cbind(bz$x,bz$y))                

                 # create Polygons object
                 poly <- Polygons(list(p), ID = x)
                 return(poly)
               }),
  proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
)

# plot
plot(sp, border = "gray", lwd = 2) # polygonize result
plot(output, border = "red",  add = TRUE) # smoothed polygons
```

I get this result:

[image: plot]

It's some days I look for the problem without success, can someone help me please?

Comment: Have you looked at this post on smoothing polygons?: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24929/8104

Comment: yes, but I don't understand how to apply it on my example is that you can help me?

Comment: i see that you have been using the code i've suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087772/create-polygon-from-set-of-points-distributed indeed the problem was also reported there, and deals with bezier smoothing. i will tackle the problem and suggest some fix ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated the original code given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087772/create-polygon-from-set-of-points-distributed/26089377#26089377

Instead of Bezier-based smoothing, you can used the smoothing suggested here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24929/8104 with the function `spline.poly` (as suggested by @aaron) which gives accurate results.